# I was looking forward ____ at the new restaurant, but it was closed

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> I was looking forward ____ at the new restaurant, but it was closed.

Are *to eat* and *to eating* both correct or only the last one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"To eating"* is the correct answer.

When using *"looking forward to"*, we follow it with a *[verb]-ing*.

Edit: We can also follow "looking forward to" with a noun.

> Example: I'm looking forward to dinner.

Comment: *If* it's followed by a verb. For instance, the following is normal: *I was looking forward to* ***your visit***.

Comment: *"visit"* in that case is a *noun*, not a verb.

Comment: That's ***exactly*** my point. Your answer doesn't say that you can follow *looking forward to* with a noun. But you can. As your answer stands, it implies that *only* a verb (using the present participle) can follow it.

Comment: OK I added that.